# Avoid the files inside my iOS app to be easily replaceable

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, realm, sdwebimage

My app is an In-house app distributed via [MobileIron](https://www.mobileiron.com). It uses [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) for the database, and also [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for image caching.

I made some tests, with [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) today, and I could see that the files are easily replaceable with this tool. This allows me to update the datas how I want, then replace the file on the iPhone, and it's done.
Anyway, it's not the case with the App Store Apps (files are not accessible via iExplorer).

I know I should may be use encryption for the Realm database, but it's more a general problem in this case.

How can I make sure that the files are not manipulated inside my app ?

Comment: As you already said, This will not be the case on live apps.

Comment: You should specify _who_ should not be able to manipulate the files. If you sent the "deployment team" an IPA, they can modify the files at will before they deploy them. The preferred way is to use VPP. You cannot reliable prevent a user to access and possibly modify their app on their device. If you are concerned of security, this is a broad topic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not talking about modifying the IPA file. I'm talking about updating the files inside the "Documents" folder of the app, on the device.

Answer (score 1):

> Once applications are wrapped with the MobileIron AppConnect wrapper they become integrated into the secure container on the device. Each app becomes a secure container whose data is encrypted, protected from unauthorized access, and removable.

[This url](https://www.mobileiron.com/en/products/appconnect) will give you more details.